# Is it possible to cause a scroll event to be fired at a given position, as if the cursor was there and the user was scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, events, scroll

The solution I currently have:

1. Identify the element at the given position using `document.elementFromPoint()`.
2. Traverse its ancestor tree to find the closest ancestor that can be scrolled (probably compare `scrollHeight` to height).
3. Scroll this element using `HTMLElement.Scroll()` method.

Is there a better method that more intrinsically triggers scrolling at a given point?

Comment: not sure if I understand what you want to be honest. But if you want to hire an event on scroll at some pre determent scroll position. Then you should attach scroll event handler and check top offset. Ones condition is true you execute you code.

You should debounce that event handler and you should clear the event if you do not need it to fire more than once.

Let me know if I got it right and I can write an answer.

Comment: Are you trying to "scroll to" any given element?

Answer (score 0):

Well something has to trigger a scroll so I'll use the **mouseover** event and **e.scrollIntoView()** to make the screen scroll. Demo code follows...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<div id="First" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:0px; background:red; color:white;" onmouseover="Second.scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});">First</div>

<div id="Second" style="position:absolute; top:1000px; left:0px; background:blue; color:white;" onmouseover="Third.scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});">Second</div>

<div id="Third" style="position:absolute; top:2000px; left:0px; background:green; color:white;" onmouseover="First.scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'});">Third</div>

</body>
</html>
```